# service account for gitlab container registry

Tags: gitlab, docker-registry

We would like to use our private gitlab container registry in AWS ECS. When accessing the registry, we get 403 as expected. Now we need a service account to access the registry, but I cannot figure out how to create them.

The gitlab ci seems to have a global user "gitlab-ci-token" which has access to the registry. 

`docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN`

see https://about.gitlab.com/2016/05/23/gitlab-container-registry/

Is there any possibility to create non-project users/api tokens that can access the registry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a user within your organisation (gitlabci@domain.abc) and create a Personal Access Token for that user. It took me some time to figure out you need to replace gitlab-ci-token with that users email adres in order to successfully login.

Comment: Yes, that's our workaround. But we have to add the user to each and every project.